# How can I express a time duration in seconds?

Tags: c#

I'm reading some specifications and there is one point that says I need a variable that will represent time in seconds. Maybe this is an easy question, but how can I express a time duration in seconds in C#?

Comment: What time?  User-defined?  Hard-coded?  `DateTime.Now`?  How about `DateTime.Now.Second.ToString()`?

Comment: By "time", do you mean "time of day" or "time span"?

Comment: It would help to know more about this requirement of yours.  Where do you arrive at the seconds to store, since you say you need a variable.  Seconds should be an `Int32`, unless you want fractional to capture milliseconds, I suppose.  So just make an `Int32` variable and simply display it properly when the time comes, such as `00:00:12.1234`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the time in a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) type object and then you can get total seconds through [TimeSpan.TotalSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx) property

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 30); // 1 hour , 10 mins and 30 seconds. 
double seconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: The reason `TotalSeconds` returns a double is the `TimeSpan` can hold milliseconds and they need to be represented in the `TotalSeconds` result. (I only say this because it took me a bit to understand that when I was first learning C# myself)